# SetC#: Setting FlatStyle programmatically

Tags: c#

I have created a class in C# that I want to use to set the attributes of some controls on every form that calls it. Something like a substitute for a Style Sheet. It works great for some attributes but not for others. For example, FlatStyle gives an error "Control does not contain a definition for 'FlatStyle'...

```
public static void SetAttributesTEST(Form thisForm)
{
foreach (Control C in CallingForm.Controls)
            {
                if (C is TextBox)
                {
                    C.ForeColor = Color.SlateGray;
                    C.BackColor = Color.White;
                    C.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
                }
                if (C is Label)
                {
                    C.ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                    C.BackColor = Color.White;
                    C.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
                }
                if (C is Button)
                {
                    C.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    C.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                    C.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
                    C.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                }
}
}
```

Comment: `((Button)C).FlatStyle = ...`

Comment: Your parameter and your loop don't seem to be matching.

Answer (score 1):

C# 7 Sugar: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

```
        foreach (Control control in Controls)
        {
            control.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 12, FontStyle.Regular);

            switch (control)
            {
                case TextBox tbx:
                    tbx.ForeColor = Color.SlateGray;
                    tbx.BackColor = Color.White;
                    break;

                case Label lbl:
                    lbl.ForeColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                    lbl.BackColor = Color.White;
                    break;

                case Button btn:
                    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    btn.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    break;
            }
        }
```